# Ajax and fullCalendar - refetchEvents

Tags: python, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using the great FullCalendar but have a problem with refetchEvents.

With a python-script I add a new event in a google-Calendar. The google-Calendar is the eventSource for my FullCalendar. After that is done I try to reload the eventSource. But the just added event doesn't appear although I'm quite sure that it is inserted in the google-Calendar at this moment. After pushing next and back I get the new event. Here is the relevant jquery-Part:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"cgi-bin/termin_insert.py",
        data: JSON.stringify(myevent),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data,success,xhr){
                  alert(data.eventId);
                  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        },
        error:function(){
                ...do something
        }
});
```

In the success-Part the correct google-eventId is alerted. So I know, that the event is really already inserted.

I can work around the problem if I double the command 'refetchEvents'. When I use 'rerenderEvents', there is no difference at all.

It seems to me as if the xml-feed of the google-Calendar is renewed a little bit later after a successful insert of a new event. But I wonder if the main problem is sitting in front of the screen...

Answer (score 0):

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324717) the user had a similar problem and solved it with

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

So I decided to do some tests again although I used this method already. I don't know exactly why but now it works.

I didn't see the other question before and hope no one invested too much time...

Comment: See my updated answer in the question you mention: [refetchEvents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324717/jquery-fullcalendar-trouble-with-invoking-rerenderevents-from-ajax-success/12326746#12326746)

Comment: It doesn't work for me... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918293/update-fullcalendar-with-firebase-on-new-event