# Update FullCalendar with Firebase on new event

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fullcalendar

I'm trying to build a schedule app with full calendar and Firebase. But I can not get the the calendar to update on changes (events added/deleted/moved). The changes are reflected instantly in Firebase.

I assign data AFTER calendar `init`'ing (when loaded from Firebase). I tried assigning data array as `addEventSource` and `events` property. Seems like `eventSource` works better than assigning as `events` property. But it is not updating when data changes.

Only thing that works is manually render or removing the event in the calendar. But I want real time updating!

Here is some of my code:

```
// index.js
exports.getEvents = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        firebase.getEvents()
            .then(calendar.addEventSource)
            .then(function() {
                resolve(true);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.warn(error);
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}

// firebase.js
exports.getEvents = function() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("bookings");
        ref.on('value', function (snap) {
            var arr = obj2arr(snap.val());
            calendar.render(arr);
            resolve(arr);
        }, function (err) {
            console.warn("firebase getBookings", err);
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}

// calendar.js
exports.render = function(events) {

    if ($calendar) {
        $calendar.fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );

        //$calendar.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' );
        //$calendar.fullCalendar( {events: events} );

        //$calendar.fullCalendar( 'refetchEventSources', arr );
        //$calendar.fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );

        console.log("calender rendered");
    }
};
```

Comment: Are the lines you've commented out things you've tried that aren't working? It seems to me that `.fullCalendar({events: events}); .fullCalendar('refetchEvents');` should do it.

Comment: Yes commented lines are things I tried. Unfortunately they don't do anything. Including 'refetchEvents'... It seems to be the common suggestion. So I don't understand why it's not working here. Is the feature broken in the latest version? Or am I doing something wrong? Does it only work with both the 'events' property as data source or 'eventSource' as data source?

Answer (score 1):

In the [fullCalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/), I found:

> Event Sources should be dynamically manipulated through methods like
>   addEventSource and removeEventSource. Thusly, dynamic setting of the
>   following options is not applicable:
>
> - events
> - eventSources

Therefore I think you need to use an [EventSourceObject](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/) and do something like this:

```
// firebase.js
    // (Inside 'value' callback):
    var newEventSource = {events: snap.val()};
    calendar.render(newEventSource);

// calendar.js
exports.render = function(newSource) {
    $calendar.fullCalendar('removeEventSources');
    $calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', newSource);        

};
```